# CURL is not working to send GET request in php

Tags: php, curl

I am using CURL to send get request to a server, but it is not producing the required output.
The script works fine when loaded in browser.
It is script which combines given PNG images to GIF.

```
<?php
//generate GIF
$name = $_GET['name_of_final_gif'];
$images = $_GET['images'];
$images = json_decode($images, true);
//include GIF maker class based on GD library
include('GIFEncoder.class.php');

/******************************************************/

foreach($images as $image_link) {

    // Open the source image and add the text.
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($image_link);

    // Generate GIF from the $image
    // We want to put the binary GIF data into an array to be used later,
    //  so we use the output buffer.
    ob_start();
    imagegif($image);
    $frames[]=ob_get_contents();
    $framed[]=300; // Delay in the animation.
    ob_end_clean();

}


// Generate the animated gif and save it
$gif = new GIFEncoder($frames,$framed,0,2,0,0,0,'bin');
$fp = fopen("gifs/$name", 'w');
fwrite($fp, $gif->GetAnimation());
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Update:
Below is my CURL code which is on another server and is sending GET request to this script which is hosted on another server:

```
$images = $class_name->get_images_links(); // get image links from database in JSON FORMAT
$name = "something.gif"; //name for output GIF image
$url = "http://example.com/make_gif.php?images=$images&&name_of_final_gif=$name"; 

// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: I don't see the CURL usage in your code...

Comment: Where is cURL? What output are you getting? There is not enough information here.

Comment: Where is your CURL call?

Comment: I have added my CURL code above now, please have a look

Comment: Passing a JSON object in $_GET method is not a good practice even though is working. Please also share the output or result of running these scripts.

Comment: You still have not said what result you are currently getting. Also, if you are sending a JSON array of file paths, Is that string too large for a $_GET parameter? There is a limit.

Comment: @Christian When I execute the cURL script , the page is just loading for a long time until timeout occurs and it displays a page saying "405 Not Allowed"

Comment: No I am not exceeding the limit for $_GET parameter because when I pass those parameters to the URL from my browser script works fine .
And regarding cURL request, it is successfully being sent to the URL as if I add some lines of code like using mail function to send me mails when the script is executed , so it works and sends me mail when the URL is called from cURL but its not producing any output and the page from which I execute the cURL script says "405 not allowed" when I echo the cURL response

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/make_gif.php?images=$images&&name_of_final_gif=$name");
curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: You need to add an explanation. Code-only answers aren't encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function curl($url) {
        // Assigning cURL options to an array
        $options = Array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,  // Setting cURL's option to return the webpage data
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,  // Setting cURL to follow 'location' HTTP headers
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE, // Automatically set the referer where following 'location' HTTP headers
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,  // Setting the maximum amount of time for cURL to execute queries
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, // Setting the maximum number of redirections to follow
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8",  // Setting the useragent
            CURLOPT_URL => $url, // Setting cURL's URL option with the $url variable passed into the function

        );

        $ch = curl_init();  // Initialising cURL



        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);   // Setting cURL's options using the previously assigned array data in $options

        $data = curl_exec($ch); // Executing the cURL request and assigning the returned data to the $data variable

        curl_close($ch);    // Closing cURL

        return $data;   // Returning the data from the function 
    }

    $page = curl($link);
```